How to make a non-indexed text field indexed in Elasticsearch
Elasticsearch index has the cityName field
"cityName": {
  "type": "text", 
  "index": false
}

How to make this field indexed? To reindex completely? Or is there a different way to do this? I am using Elasticsearch 7.1 version.

It's Possible to Make a Field Indexed
Yes, there are ways to make a field indexed.
update_by_query
The first way is update_by_query
Mapping with a non-indexed field
PUT /index_field
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "cityName": {
                "type": "text",
                "index": false
            }
        }
    }
}

Document
PUT /index_field/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"cityName":"Kungur"}

update_by_query copies the cityName field into the city_name_indexed field
POST /index_field/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source['city_name_indexed'] = ctx._source['cityName']"
    }
}

Let's search by a full-text query
GET /index_field/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "city_name_indexed": "kungur"
        }
    }
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "index_field",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 0.2876821,
                "_source" : {
                    "cityName" : "Kungur",
                    "city_name_indexed" : "Kungur"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Let's discover mapping by GET /index_field/_mapping
Response
{
    "index_field" : {
        "mappings" : {
            "properties" : {
                "cityName" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "index" : false
                },
                "city_name_indexed" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Now the city_name_indexed field is indexed
Updating Mapping
The second way is to update mapping by a query
PUT /index_field/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
        "city_name_indexed_too": { "type": "text"}
    }
}

Then update_by_query with the  city_name_indexed_too field
